# Is there a usb c 100w power splitter hub?

Tags: power-supply, usb-c, power-bank

I have an Anker 240w (140w+100w) charger that I use to charge my laptops or my power bank (140w) but that’s it.

Many times I’m trying my to charge multiple lower powered devices e.g. 4 trackers that take 15-20w each but there aren’t enough ports.

Having 140w available but using it to charge one device at 20w seems a waste.

Are there any hubs or anything that can take 140/100w and charge multiple devices at something like 20w per device?

As a note the charger and power bank both have one port that can output 140w.

Edit:
To clarify. My goal is to charge stuff aka no data transfer. From one high power(1x100w) to multiple low power(5x20w)
Instead of buying a new big plugin charger with like 10 ports, I could use a “hub” with my current usb c charger to charge multiple low powered items.  Also i could use a “hub” with my power bank so then I can charge multiple low powered items on the go

Comment: Do you have a hub that connects teh computer to other devices and is plugged into the mains?)  I am confused, if you have a powered hub then what does it matter what your charger and power bank do?  Forget about what you have.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @RohitGupta The hub would need to support USB-PD, which is nontrivial.

Comment: There are products called "power delivery hubs" that do not work like a USB data hub, they just plug into the wall and provide lots of power to each port individually. Some new models support USB-C PD on more than one port. Anker makes a couple IIRC. If you need many ports then this will be very expensive.

Comment: Simply what I’m trying to do is charge stuff. No data transfer or anything like that. going from a high power port(1x100w) to multiple smaller powered ports(5x20w).

Comment: So is using multiple chargers from a power bar not an option? Or is mains power not an option at all here? These power delivery "hubs" are always designed to use mains power and do not connect to a USB-C "source" at all, they *are* the USB-C source (multiple individual chargers in one unit).

Comment: The idea is that I can plug a “hub” into the wall charger and then if needed I can charge on the go by plugging the “hub” into the power bank.

Comment: I think you'll probably have more luck looking for a bigger power bank that has more ports on it. When you have access to wall power you can simply use more chargers plugged into a power bar and don't need a hub at all (this would be cheaper too).

Comment: There aren’t many powerbanks that have 5+ ports and if they do they can’t output the 100w needed to charge my laptop. Also I’m trying to have the least amount of things plugged into the walls. The thought is, I can use a charger or power bank to power my laptop but if needed I can plug in a “hub” and power multiple low powered devices.

Comment: Here is a hypothetical example scenario. 
I’m not near any wall sockets and I’m playing Tetris effect on the quest 3 with a ps5 controlller while streaming to my phone and my friend connects to the game on a Nintendo switch. 
The switch,quest,iPhone and controller all are usb c and require 20w. But I only have 1 100w usb c port on the power bank. the power bank has enough power to charge all of them to full battery but no way to connect them all in

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few devices which can take DC input and then provide multiple USB ports for charging purposes.

The [SlimQ DC Extender](https://slimq.life/products/dc-to-usb-extender-for-150w-240) takes 5-24V DC input via a 5.5mm x 2.5mm barrel connector and can provide two USB C devices with 100W and two USB A devices with 30W max  (of course the latter is not standard).

YZXStudio had and somewhat still has multiple such devices, they call them car chargers. These include the ZC918P, ZC920 and more. Typically you can find them on aliexpress and taobao under various sellers, it's fairly pointless to link as the sellers change frequently. These also can take USB C PD input directly.

Comment: I bought the SlimQ dc extender(£25) and combined with a 20v/100w usb c to barrel adapter means I now have a usb c hub that can split/share the power. 
The only thing is, I can’t find any hubs that take usb c as an input and are cheap, most are £45+.

Comment: a) you didn't include price requirements in the original question b) this is all there is

Answer (score 0):

A USB power source can deliver voltages from 5V to 48V.  This is done via circuitry, so the device tells the power source what it wants.
As an example when the power source is delivering 240W, it is using 48V. When it is delivering 100W, it is using 20V.  **There is no wastage involved.**

To do what you are asking requires a gadget with intelligence to look at all the devices that are plugged in and request the highest voltage and then step that down to different voltages/amps for each device.  And every time you plug/unplug a device or the device gets fully charged, it will have to renegotiate what it wants from the power source.

If there is such a device it is not going to be efficient or cheap.

Your best bet is to get a multi port power source.

[Further reading on USB power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB)

Comment: the general thing i was thinking of was something like the "hub" takes in 20v@5A (100w) and then uses a chip or something to output 5v@20A (100w) which then is split into 5 x 5v@4A (20w). then I have 5 ports that can charge at 20w  (this assumes 100% efficiency which I know is impossible)